# Noob: Trying to use Input value to setup php database name

Tags: php, mysql

Am trying to use the input value as the name of the a database but it not workin

```
<html>
<form action="config.php" method="Post">
<table>
    <tr><td>DB Name: <input type="text" name="dbname"></td></tr>
    <tr><td><button type="submit" name="submit_two"> Submit</button></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</html>
```

Config.php

```
<?php
$dbname = "";
if (isset($_POST['submit_two'])){
    $dbname = test_input($_POST["dbname"]);
    $data = "CREATE DATABASE  IF NOT EXISTS $dbname";
    if (!$data) {
        echo "could not connect" . mysql_error();
    } elseif ($dbname == ""){
        echo "no";
    }else{
        echo "gud to go";
    }
    }
function test_input($data)
    {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }
?>
```

It keeps displaying "gud to go" but when i check the database nothing will be created created

Comment: What `test_input` doing here ?

Comment: $dbname =$_POST["dbname"];$data = mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE  IF NOT EXISTS $dbname");

Comment: yes @ankurbhadania is right

Comment: check was the username and password was correct. if so check was the user allowed to access the required database

Comment: please show the code you tried, because in the question it was `mysql_*` functions and in error it was `mysqli_*` functions

Comment: you are sending the data on different request. when you send data from `index1.php`, the values from `index.php` are not visibles (actually these not exits). Is the same when you send the `index.php` values

Comment: **Error no 1**

As it was saying  `Undefined variable: con` you have define $con. The $con you declared already was in the previous if loop, which will not be able to access here. SO either declare $con within scope oh these two loops or define it again in else loop

**Error 2**

`mysql_query`  does not expects mysqli variable

**Error 3**

`mysql_error()` will not except parameter.

Please post the correct errors and correct code in order to get help

Comment: show screenshot of error also

Comment: You already got an answer. Please do **not** edit your question like this again. We're not an ongoing debugging service.

Comment: i tried all that but its not working

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to run the mysql query:

```php
<?php
//first, create the connection
$con = mysqli_connect("the_db_host","db_user","db_pass");

//then, execute your code like:
$dbname = "";
if (isset($_POST['submit_two'])){
    $dbname = test_input($_POST["dbname"]);
    $data = mysqli_query($con, "CREATE DATABASE  IF NOT EXISTS $dbname");
    if (!$data) {
        echo "could not connect" . mysqli_error($con);
    } elseif ($dbname == ""){
        echo "no";
    }else{
        echo "gud to go";
    }
}

function test_input($data)
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
?>
```

**UPDATE**
By @krishna's comment, I update this answer.

About `mysqli_*` over `mysql_*` there are some reasons:

- OO interface
- Support for transactions
- Support for prepared statements
- Support multiple statements

More info in the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php)

Comment: Why dont you mention that why used `mysqli_*` function instead of `mysql_*`.

Comment: also `mysqli_error()` expects a parameter to be given

Answer (score 0):

From your code, all you did was create a couple of strings; at some point, you have to connect to the database and execute these things as SQL. See, for example, [this](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) tutorial on how to use [PDO_mysql](http://php.net/PDO_mysql).

You might also want to look at the code of similar projects, such as the items on [this list of "10 Database Management Tools for Developers"](http://codegeekz.com/10-database-management-tools-for-developers/), to get ideas and see what things do/do not work well over the long term.